# PHP - Number of units between two numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the number of units between 2 numbers that are under zero between 0 and a limit and over that limit. Here is my function. It works fine until I have to work with some huge numbers which takes a lot of time to process. I am trying to find a way to execute this code without using a loop.

```
public function getBetween($num1, $num2) {
    $limit = 500000;
    $array = array(0,0,0);

    if ($num1 >= $num2) {
        $low = $num2;
        $high = $num1;
    } else {
        $low = $num1;
        $high = $num2;
    }

    for($i=$low; $i < $high; $i++) {
        if ($i < 0) {
            $array[0]++;
        } elseif ($i >= 0 && $i < $limit) {
            $array[1]++;
        } else {
            $array[2]++;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I have started to split my loop into elseif statements but this is getting messy really quick and I will also have to eventually be able to set more than one limit which will become impossible to use.

```
if ($low < 0 && $high < 0) {
} elseif ($low < 0 && $high >= 0 && $high < $limit) {
} elseif ($low < 0 && $high >= $limit) {
} elseif ($low >= 0 && $low < $limit && $high < 0) {
} elseif ($low >= 0 && $low < $limit && $high >= 0 && $high < $limit) {
} elseif ($low >= 0 && $low < $limit && $high >= $limit) {
} elseif ($low >= $limit && $high < 0) {
} elseif ($low >= $limit && $high >= 0 && $high < $limit) {
} elseif ($low >= $limit && $high >= $limit) {
}
```

I am trying to find a clean way to do it. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the array I'm trying to get.
If my limit was 500, `$num1` = -100 and `$num2` = 700 i would get the array

```
$array[0] = 100
$array[1] = 500
$array[2] = 200
```

Comment: Sorry I just read that `I will also have to eventually be able to set more than one limit`, I assume my answer below doesn't fit with it. Could you give an example of what result is expected with more than one limit?

Comment: I am currently not a 100% sure of how I'm going to do it with more that one limit. But I would get an array of limits
$limits = array(0, 500, 2000, 10000);
And I will check the number of units before 0, between 0 and 500, between 500 and 2000, between 2000 and 10000, over 10000. Like I said, I'm not sure of how to do it but I will depend on the solution that I end up using.

Comment: I just edited my answer with something that works with as many limits as you want.

Comment: could the limit be < 0 ?

Comment: I haven't checked if caCtus's answer supports a limit under 0, but for the problem that I'm currently working on the limit will never be under 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it (didn't run a PHP script but I tried it "manually" with a few examples).

You still have loops, but only one iteration per limit (instead of one per unit).

```
// Example datas
$limits = array(0, 500, 800);
$low = -100;
$high = 1000;

$splittedResults = array();

// Get total of units
$totalUnits = abs($high - $low);

$totalCounted = 0;
foreach($limits as $limit) {
    if ($low > $limit) {
    // Nothing under the limit
        $nbUnderLimit = 0;
    } elseif($high < $limit) {
    // Both values under the limit
        $nbUnderLimit = $totalUnits;
    } else {
    // $low under the limit and $high over it
        $nbUnderLimit = abs($limit - $low);
    }

    // Here we know how much units are under current limit in total.
    // We want to know how much are between previous limit and current limit.

    // Assuming that limits are sorted ascending, we have to remove already counted units.
    $nbBetweenLimits = $nbUnderLimit - $totalCounted;

    $splittedResults[] = $nbBetweenLimits;
    $totalCounted += $nbBetweenLimits;
}

// Finally, number of units that are over the last limit (the rest)
$splittedResults[] = $totalUnits - $totalCounted;
```

Comment: No problem, these small algorithmic problems are my favourites! Always interesting to find the answer (and compare it with other's to see what is wrong in mine, sometimes there are several ways to do it). :) I fixed a mistake in the `Both values under the limit` line (I was using the wrong variable).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of the numbers with range() and use array_filter

```
$count = sizeof(array_filter (range(0,800), function($value){ return ($value > 500); }));
```

And one for < as well etc.

You only need to define range array once, separately.

Comment: Good idea (I always forget to have a look at the `array` functions, most of them are really useful though), but won't it still take some time to process with huge values? (This is a real question, not a free criticism.)

Comment: Hard to say, i only have 32 bit access at this moment and it run 400k  range in a  fraction of a second.

Comment: Using range is indeed more clean, but it takes 48x times longer than using the function with the loop that I am currently using.

Comment: indeed it is - as it would count each value.
Any built in function would  still use loops.